# Books for a conceptual understanding of linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, soft-question, big-list

I've been working Linear Algebra a lot recently; I've been using *Schaum's Outlines for Linear Algebra* to supplement my understanding. Unfortunately, as nice and organized and Schaum's tends to be, the text fails to provide the reader with a conceptual understanding of even the most rudimentary components of linear algebra, e.g. dot products, cross products, projections, etc.

I've already read through the post located at
[Book Recommendations for Linear Algebra Proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612242/book-recommendations-for-linear-algebra-proofs)

Now, I should mention that the above link does not quite satisfy what I am looking for because the author of Schaum's *does* provide proofs for the theorems he provides, but the theorems are largely computational; perhaps one of the books mentioned at the aforementioned link provide more coneptually ground proofs. Ultimately, I'm looking for Linear Algebra texts that walk the reader through a step-by-step conceptual understanding of the principles of Linear Algebra, should one exist. I suspect that *Linear Algebra Done Right* may be a good recommendation for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Schaum's text, but could you elaborate on what exactly a "conceptually ground" proof might look like?

Comment: the book of Sheldon Axler is excellent for this task, I can't think in something better

Comment: This is all subjective of course  but I find "Linear Algebra Done Right" to be the opposite what is claims to be, in words, this is how subject matter should NOT be taught. Instead, try some on line resources, I would recommend: 1.https://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/readings.htm or 2.https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~linear/linear-guest.pdf

Comment: @DylanC.Beck It doesn't have to be specific to proofs. An example of my frustration with Schaum's is that they give the definition of the dot product of two vectors without explaining what the dot product is useful for or how it relates to projections. A similar argument can be made about cross products: hearty in definition but lacking in abstract application.

Comment: If you're interested particularly in the geometric aspects of linear algebra, I recommend my own text (Shifrin and Adams, *Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach*), which is written in such a way as to help students learn to approach proofs. You can also check out appropriate ones of my YouTube lectures (based on a different text, covering both linear algebra and multivariable calculus/analysis), linked in my profile.

Comment: I like the book here: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/linalg.pdf. It is in a similar style to Linear Algebra Done Right, but is better in some ways.

Comment: One of the cheapest is Linear Algebra For Dummies for about $\$14$. Others like the  ones I used in college are upwards of $\$50$ on amazon.

Comment: You might take a look at some of Gilbert Strang's online lectures on linear algebra. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=1 Then if you like his approach you can try his book *Introduction to Linear Algebra*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduction to Linear Analysis by Kreider, Kuller, Ostberg, ...
Makes a clear and unified treatment of Linear algebra and differential equations, both ordinary and partial.